# getCurrentUser not going null even i logged out using Parse sdk

Tags: parse-platform

How to manage session with Parse SDK?

I have used SharedPrefences to locally store the session user info, and checked on the start whether move the user to Home Screen or Login screen. Is this the right process or there is an option to maintain session automatically without using SharedPrefecences.

Comment: Where do you initialize Parse ??

Comment: can you please post the initialization of parse in your Application class? (DON'T include your private keys just post the methods calls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just use SharedPrefences according to your Login and SignUp Activity besides you can also use Parse Session Management..**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution to the first problem as even I failed to get it working. One of the workaround is to store the user information in shared preferences temporarily when he/she logs in and clear them when user logs out of the app.

```
    private void setUserPreferences(String username){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("DEFAULT_SP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("username", username);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private String getUserPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("DEFAULT_SP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString("username", null);
    }

    private void clearUserPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("DEFAULT_SP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Now you can call these functions when you log into the app and log out of the app. Not a viable solution but its all what I've got for the time being.

Also, you cannot login using email-id in parse, you will need username for that. So what you can do is to find the username associated with that email and then log into parse using that username.

```
private String mUsername=null;
private void getParseUsername(String email){
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
    query.whereEqualTo("email", email);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                //assuming you don't have same email id's in the parse database
                //, I don't think that's even allowed.
                mUsername = parseList.get(0).getString("");
            } else {
                Log.d("parseList", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For retrieving user info, you can simply type this code:

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername()
```

For your fourth question, if I understand it correctly, you don't want user to register with a mobile number which is already registered.

```
private boolean mDuplicatePhoneNo=false;
private void isPhoneNumberDuplicate(String phoneNo)
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
    //Here phone_no is the field name in which you have stored your phone numbers
    //Make sure they are in string format.
    query.whereEqualTo("phone_no", phone);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if(phoneNo.equals(parseList.get(0).getString("phone_no"))){
                    mDuplicatePhoneNo=true;
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("parseList", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
});
```

Also make sure to visit https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#getting-started
for a better guide.